# Date Difference Changes to 42000 while using LAG function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Question: Find out no follow-up appointments to the call within the following 7 days for a particular Patient

My query:

```
  select *, DATEDIFF(DAY, (APPOINTMENT_DATE - LAG(APPOINTMENT_DATE) 
  over (ORDER BY PATIENT_ID)), APPOINTMENT_DATE) as DIFFERENCE from [dbo]. 
  [Appointment Data]
```

Problems:

1.DIFFERENCE CHANGES to some crazy format because of datetime may be.

2.Is my query right? How do I find difference for each customer? I know I have to apply group by but I am little confused.

PLS HELP!

Dataset:

```
APPOINTMENT_DATE             PATIENT_ID         DIFFERENCE                                                  

2010-05-06 00:00:00.000      00051101          NULL
2010-04-11 00:00:00.000      00101005          40302
2010-05-06 00:00:00.000      00130521          40277
2010-02-07 00:00:00.000      00130521          40302
```

Comment: pls provide sample data and also in your query check values for APPOINTMENT_DATE ,LAG(APPOINTMENT_DATE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have several mistakes in your query:

1) You should use column `PATIENT_ID` in partitioning and order by `APPOINTMENT_DATE` in `LAG` function

2) You have unnecessary subtraction in `DATEDIFF` function

So, your query should be something like:

```
select 
    *, datediff(dd, lag(APPOINTMENT_DATE) over (partition by PATIENT_ID order by APPOINTMENT_DATE), APPOINTMENT_DATE)
from 
    [dbo].[Appointment Data]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,
DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(APPOINTMENT_DATE) over (ORDER BY PATIENT_ID), APPOINTMENT_DATE) as DIFFERENCE
from [dbo].[Appointment Data]
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------+------------+------------+
|   APPOINTMENT_DATE    | PATIENT_ID | DIFFERENCE |
+-----------------------+------------+------------+
| 5/6/2010 12:00:00 AM  |   00051101 |       null |
| 4/11/2010 12:00:00 AM |   00101005 |        -25 |
| 5/6/2010 12:00:00 AM  |   00130521 |         25 |
| 2/7/2010 12:00:00 AM  |   00130521 |        -88 |
+-----------------------+------------+------------+
```

If you switch the dates, the result will be different.

```
select *,
DATEDIFF(DAY, APPOINTMENT_DATE, LAG(APPOINTMENT_DATE) over (ORDER BY PATIENT_ID)) as DIFFERENCE
from [dbo].[Appointment Data]
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------+------------+------------+
|   APPOINTMENT_DATE    | PATIENT_ID | DIFFERENCE |
+-----------------------+------------+------------+
| 5/6/2010 12:00:00 AM  |   00051101 |       null |
| 4/11/2010 12:00:00 AM |   00101005 |         25 |
| 5/6/2010 12:00:00 AM  |   00130521 |        -25 |
| 2/7/2010 12:00:00 AM  |   00130521 |         88 |
+-----------------------+------------+------------+
```